# Odd jagged appearance of mip-mapped textures in OpenGL using "glGenerateMipmap"

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

I am experimenting with mip-maps for the first time in OpenGL. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/#mipmaps), which builds on [this code](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/tree/master/tutorial05_textured_cube). In the [fragment shader](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/blob/master/tutorial05_textured_cube/TextureFragmentShader.fragmentshader) I did the following modification:

```
vec2 uv = UV;
uv.y = 1-UV.y;
color = texture( myTextureSampler, uv, 1 ).rgb;
```

... which flips the y axis values (part of the tutorial exercise to get the texture right). **It also sets the LOD bias on the final row, so that I can view the coarser details in the texture.**

I also modified the [cpp file](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/blob/master/tutorial05_textured_cube/tutorial05.cpp) of the tutorial:

line 29, turned off super-sampling anti-aliasing:

```
// glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
```

line 87, create the mip-maps:

```
GLuint Texture = loadDDS("uvtemplate.DDS"); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

from line 183, implemented simple camera movement (to get a good overview of its appearance):

```
...
GLfloat rot = 0.0;
do{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(programID);

    rot += 0.003;
    View       = glm::lookAt(
                            glm::vec3(glm::cos(rot)*4.8, glm::cos(rot/3)*1.3+ 1.3 ,glm::sin(rot)*2.9), 
                            glm::vec3(0,0,0), 
                            glm::vec3(0,1,0)); 
    MVP        = Projection * View * Model; 
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    ...
```

I expected to see a blurred version of the [input texture](https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl/blob/master/tutorial05_textured_cube/uvtemplate.tga?raw=true), instead it looks awful: [image]

The jagged edges on the bottom side of the "1" makes no sense to me at all. They appear on some of the figures in the texture, but not others.

The input texture format is .DDS, could that somehow be the source of the problem? Could it be a bug in my driver? I am on Ubuntu Linux 16.04, with the newest drivers as found in the PPA:s. Searched online, found nothing on this topic.

**edit**: I also experimented with some openGL settings, like this:

```
glHint(GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT, GL_NICEST);

GLfloat anisoVal;
glGetFloatv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, &anisoVal);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, anisoVal);
```

but it did nothing.

Comment: Why do you use a bias of 1 (`texture( myTextureSampler, uv, 1)`)? The bias is add to the level of detail. Tr it without the bias `texture( myTextureSampler, uv)`

Comment: The point of putting the bias is to investigate what the different LODs of the mip map will look like. I am not interested in rendering in the end, but using the built in, optimized openGL routines/hardware to make fast pyramid expansions for images. However, if I do remove the lod, the artefacts still remain, although become less easy to spot.

Comment: You can use [`textureLod`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureLod.xhtml) to specify the explicit level-of-detail.

Comment: @Rabbid76, Thank you, for the advice. I am sure that function will come in handy! Right now, I like the visualization of the cube and using a LOD bias instead of static look up. As the cube rotates, I will get a feel for how the mip-map levels change over the animation. If I used textureLod, I guess the textures would never change (which will be good for my experimentation as well)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this artifacts (Debian 9.5, NVidia  410.57), nor can I think up of a good explanation for what you posted on the screenshots. What GPU/driver are you using?

Comment: I am now sitting at a different location, and have tried the same code on 2 other computers. The jagged edges disappear. Both of these computers have Ubuntu (as the original machine) but with different hardware. The computer I was working on has an intel chip, and will check the model and driver version tomorrow. This must surely be a bug in the driver.

Comment: I am on ubuntu 16.04, HW info: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)

Comment: I have found a seemingly identical laptop as mine (another hp elitebook with same hardware), also with ubuntu 16.04, and same drivers as I understand it. The same exe file renders without the artifacts. I am totally perplexed, and will continue to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem was an old driver. The computer I was working on had a special setup where non-standard PPAs had replaced the ubuntu (Canonical) supported ones. I could not access some of those outside of a special intra-net (at customer). Didnt read the error messages at sudo apt-get update.

The lesson from my question: The sort of bugs that can arise, and how they can bite you is unpredictable if you do not update your graphics drivers.... even if you think you have updated them.... double and tripple check. Thanks to @derhass and @Rabbid76 for leaving helpful remarks.